# optpase returns true class while string is provided in cmd line arguments

Tags: ruby, optparse

I'm stuck in a totally stupid situation. When I use the snippet below,
despite my command line being "./the_script.rb -s serv"  and I check
the value of the service variable within the code, it's always taken
to be of boolean class by optparse. So I cannot get my string from the
command line...

any ideas ?

```
opt = OptionParser.new do |opt|

 opt.on('-s','--service','twitter (tw) or identica (id)') do |val| 
   service = val.to_s 
 end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Python programmer, not a Ruby one, but browsing the examples in the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/) for this, I'd say the default behavior as you have it is to act as a boolean. You need to specify more parameters for it to actually *store* the value.

```
opts.on("-s", "--service [SERVICE]", [:twitter, :identica], "Select a service (Twitter or Identica)" do |service|
    options.service = service
end
```

Then `options.service` should have the designated service. I think... Hey, it's Ruby. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call `opt.parse!` on the block somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As you may see in the in code documentation of `optparse.rb` (in `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/optparse.rb` for me) under "`==== Using Built-in Conversions`", , you have to specify the string of the second argument to the `on` method:

```
 173 # ==== Using Built-in Conversions
 174 #
 175 # As an example, the built-in +Time+ conversion is used. The other built-in
 176 # conversions behave in the same way.
 177 # OptionParser will attempt to parse the argument
 178 # as a +Time+. If it succeeds, that time will be passed to the
 179 # handler block. Otherwise, an exception will be raised.
 180 #
 181 #   require 'optparse'
 182 #   require 'optparse/time'
 183 #   OptionParser.new do |parser|
 184 #     parser.on("-t", "--time [TIME]", Time, "Begin execution at given time") do |time|
 185 #       p time
 186 #     end
 187 #   end.parse!
 188 #
```

Thus

```
opt.on('-s','--service [String]','twitter (tw) or identica (id)') do |val|
```